# NLTK "generate" function: How to get back returned text?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm a Python noob, so bear with me.

I'm trying to work with the NLTK library, and in particular the 'generate' function. It looks like from the documentation this function simply prints its result (http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.text-pysrc.html). I would like to manipulate the resulting text prior to printing it to the screen, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this function to return its text.

How would I go about getting the output of this function? Do I have to change the function to return the result instead of printing it?

UPDATE: I found this link which kinda does it, but it feels pretty darn hacky. http://northernplanets.blogspot.com/2006/07/capturing-output-of-print-in-python.html Is this the best I can hope for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `generate` is doing is generating a trigram model if none exists, then calling

```
text = self._trigram_model.generate(length)
```

and wrapping and printing it.

Just take the parts you want -- possibly just the above line (with `self` replaced by the instance name), or possibly the whole thing, as below, with the final `print` replaced with `return`.

```
def generate(self, length=100):
    if '_trigram_model' not in self.__dict__: 
        estimator = lambda fdist, bins: LidstoneProbDist(fdist, 0.2)
        self._trigram_model = NgramModel(3, self, estimator)
    text = self._trigram_model.generate(length)
    return tokenwrap(text) # or just text if you don't want to wrap
```

And then you can just call it with a manually passed instance as the first argument.

Comment: Hi agf, thanks for the response; I'm a bit confused though. What would be the manually passed instance that I would pass this function?

Comment: @thekevinscott Whatever object you were calling `obj.generate()` on, you call `text = generate(obj)` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Go into Python26/site-packages/nltk/text.py and change the "generate" function:

```
     def generate(self, length=100):
        if '_trigram_model' not in self.__dict__:
            print "Building ngram index..."
            estimator = lambda fdist, bins: LidstoneProbDist(fdist, 0.2)
            self._trigram_model = NgramModel(3, self, estimator)
        text = self._trigram_model.generate(length)
        text_gen = tokenwrap(text)
        print text_gen
        return text_gen`
```

Comment: You shouldn't change `generate` in site-packages -- this is a _terrible_ idea. What happens when you try to use it as originally written for another project, or it gets called internally, etc?

Comment: The better way if you *really* want to patch some package fn is to define your function `my_hacked_generate()`, then after `import nltk` do `nltk.parse.generate = my_hacked_generate`. (cc: @agf) But don't touch the source files.